# How to get 'Commands' button working in Office Addins?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have issue that any function I use for button does not work + I don't know how to debug Office Commands.

```
Excel Version 1904 (build 11527.20004)
```

When I use F12 debugger and attach to the IE process for my addin (task pane), then when I click the button I'll get unhandled exception and prompt to attach debugger, If I do so with my VS 2017, I will get this:

> Unhandled exception at line 18, column 27179 in
>   https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js
>   0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'filter' occurred

What I did:
 - manifest seems correct (validation passed), it has all the nodes, buttons are visible in the ribbon.
 - after enabling loopback exemption (I run it on my localhost together with IIS server) reference to the DesktopFunctionFile seems fine, fiddler shows it is retrieved correctly
 - for the "ExecuteFunction" I used multiple functions like
    - Show Custom Dialog (nothing happens)
    - Write some data into the sheet (nothing happens)
    - any used console.log does not show anywhere (I was expecting to see it in the Runtime log).
 - I use the event.completed();

I only see "RibbonTest is working on Test" at the bottom of Excel when clicked on "Test" button. "RibbonTest" is name of my addin.

I used this sample as a base for my 'FunctionFile' html (just head part):
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/blob/2304d66438323239eb81e61b734bd8b231cc4615/SimpleDialogSampleWeb/FunctionFile.html

```
<head> 
   <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var clickEvent;
        // The initialize function must be defined each time a new page is loaded
        (function () {
            Office.initialize = function (reason) {
               // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
            };
        })();
        // Wrap the writeToDoc in showNotification because showNotification is called
        // in DialogHelper.js but must be defined differently when the dialog is called
        // from a task pane instead of a custom menu command.
        function showNotification(event)
        {
            clickEvent = event;
            writeToDoc();
            //Required, call event.completed to let the platform know you are done processing.
            clickEvent.completed();
        }

        function writeToDoc()
        {
            console.log("WriteToDoc.");
            Excel.run(function (context) {
                var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                var range = sheet.getRange("B2");
                range.values = [[ 5 ]];
                return context.sync();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Does anyone know how to debug the 'Commands' in Office Addins?
Any tip for getting this running is more than welcome!
Thanks.

Comment: I'll see if I can get some help. In the meantime, can you try sideloading to Office Online and debugging there: [Debugging in Office Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online).

Comment: I can tell you, in the meantime, that when you launch a FunctionFile.html from an Add-in Command, you are launching an entirely separate instance of the browser and its JavaScript engine from the task pane's instance. So using F12 on the task pane instance won't help you debug the Add-in Command.

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you for the tip with Excel Online... actually it works there!!! So there is some issue with the Windows Desktop version. I would bet that the root of the problem is that it is UWP sandbox but I have allowed loopback exemption for my app (and actually for all apps in Fiddler, just to be sure) and it did not help (cleaning up and enabling everything again did not help).

Comment: @RickKirkham as for te F12 - yes I knew that (otherwise I would not ask for how to debug). I added that information about exception cause it might be somehow connected to the fact, that it does not work locally. But as commented above, the button issue will be rather connected to the UWP. Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: When you say it works on Excel Online, do you mean you can debug there or just that the add-in works there?

Comment: @RickKirkham Button is working fine, debugging as well.

Comment: OK. I'll make Office Online the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the JavaScript of an Add-in Command, you need to [debug it with Office Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online).

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking for answer how to debug it on desktop + more importantly I'd like to know why it does not work on desktop excel.

Comment: @4tt1 I appreciate your patience. I think we've got a kind of a kind of "sprawl" or "mission creep" with this question. The only sentence in your question that ends with a "?" is "Does anyone know how to debug the 'Commands' in Office Addins?". I think that is answered now (thanks you your help!). The different question of your code working in Online, but not desktop, should be raised at [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) since it is almost certainly a bug in Office desktop.

Comment: I don't agree. In my post is clearly stated environment. You proposed to test Excel Online, I did that, but it does not suddenly change the game.It only makes the things more clear - that it does not work on desktop and that we obviously don't have any capability to debug there. However I won't push it. I'll raise the bug.
Thank you for the help, anyway.